# Disabling HTTP methods and using Force HTTP with mod_rewrite in Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

In my virtual host file on Apache, I want to disable HTTP methods and use force https as well. How will the mod_rewrite rules and conditions work? I have following in virtual host file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(OPTIONS|TRACE)
RewriteRule .* - [F]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [L,R]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the mod-rewrite rule for disabling HTTP options methods in "ssl.conf" file solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For the requirements you noted, the Rewrites you listed seem correct. The first Cond/Rule pair returns a 403 Forbidden for any requests that use the OPTIONS or TRACE methods. The second Cond/Rule pair redirects any http request over to https and preserves the original hostname and URI.

Comment: Adding the mod-rewrite rule for disabling HTTP options methods in "ssl.conf" file solved the issue.